# What is bootstrap listener in the context of Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring

I am studying Spring framework, in web.xml I added following which is a bootstrap listener. Can anyone give me a proper idea of what is a bootstrap listener?

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can see the doc here: [ContextLoadListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html)

> Bootstrap listener to start up and shut down Spring's root [WebApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html). Simply delegates to `ContextLoader` as well as to `ContextCleanupListener`.
>
> This listener should be registered after `Log4jConfigListener` in web.xml, if the latter is used.
>
> As of Spring 3.1, `ContextLoaderListener` supports injecting the root web application context via the `ContextLoaderListener(WebApplicationContext)` constructor, allowing for programmatic configuration in Servlet 3.0+ environments. See [WebApplicationInitializer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) for usage examples...

Answer (score 2):

It's an [event listener](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000654) as defined in the servlet standard. Basically, it's a way to execute code when the servlet container has started the web app.

Spring's `ContextLoaderListener` uses this mechanism to create the `WebApplicationContext`, which involves reading and parsing all bean configuration XML files, as well as (depending on the configuration) instantiating the singleton beans.